# msiexec logging not working

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am working on a powershell script but it seems like my powershell installer logging ain't working. It says that my install parameters are wrong.

But if I read it on there website it should work:

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html

```
$serviceLogging = Join-Path $logginPath "$service.log";

$arg1 = "/qn";
$arg2 = "/L*V $serviceLogging";
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i $service $arg1$arg2" -Wait;
```

Then the screen pops up with the following error:

```
Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.15063.0 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]

Install Options
    </package | /i> <Product.msi>
        Installs or configures a product
    /a <Product.msi>
        Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
    /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
        Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
    </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Uninstalls the product
Display Options
    /quiet
        Quiet mode, no user interaction
    /passive
        Unattended mode - progress bar only
    /q[n|b|r|f]
        Sets user interface level
        n - No UI
        b - Basic UI
        r - Reduced UI
        f - Full UI (default)
    /help
        Help information
Restart Options
    /norestart
        Do not restart after the installation is complete
    /promptrestart
        Prompts the user for restart if necessary
    /forcerestart
        Always restart the computer after installation
Logging Options
    /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] <LogFile>
        i - Status messages
        w - Nonfatal warnings
        e - All error messages
        a - Start-up of actions
        r - Action-specific records
        u - User requests
        c - Initial UI parameters
        m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
        o - Out-of-disk-space messages
        p - Terminal properties
        v - Verbose output
        x - Extra debugging information
        + - Append to existing log file
        ! - Flush each line to the log
        * - Log all information, except for v and x options
    /log <LogFile>
        Equivalent of /l* <LogFile>
Update Options
    /update <Update1.msp>[;Update2.msp]
        Applies update(s)
    /uninstall <PatchCodeGuid>[;Update2.msp] /package <Product.msi | 
<ProductCode>
    Remove update(s) for a product
Repair Options
    /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode>
        Repairs a product
        p - only if file is missing
        o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
        e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
        d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
        c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value   
    a - forces all files to be reinstalled
    u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
        m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
        s - all existing shortcuts (default)
        v - runs from source and recaches local package
Setting Public Properties
    [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]

Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the command line syntax.

Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awnser should be:

```
        $arg1 = "/qn";
        $arg2 = '/L*V "' + $serviceLogging + '"';
```

My fault was within the quotes. Also I need to make sure my directory is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Start-Process -FilePath "msifilename.msi" -ArgumentList "/qn", "/l*vs", "msifilename-logname.log" -Wait`

Comment: Even then the same screen pops-up. I added the error screen in the post now.